# Phonegap plugins with ripple emulator

Tags: cordova, couchbase, ripple, couchbase-lite

I want to use couchbase lite with my phonegap app. It comes as a phonegap plugin, but when I try to use it in ripple I get:

```
CBLite.getURL

We seem to be missing some stuff :(
```

Is it possible to use plugins or am I stuck using another emulator? (sob)

Answer (score 0):

You try Android emulator or GenyMotion instead of ripple if you use browser based (Chrome extension) Ripple.

Couchbase Lite Plugin provides an URL. You can use this URL when you perform CRUD operations.

For fast development on Cordova(PhoneGap) you try the below article.

- you can build your code using `c:\APP_FOLDER> cordova build`
- you can add your emulator for ADB using `c:\APP_FOLDER> adb devices` -just once enough- when your emulator runs
- you can replace your app on your emulator with new manufactured app using `adb install -r "platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk"`

You must have written your codes at the `onDeviceReady` event.

**Warning (before 2014/11/18):**
If you've imported Cordova Couchbase Lite Plugin using `cordova plugin add com.couchbase.lite.phonegap` you're trying plugin with **beta** version. must remove and re-import using `cordova plugin add https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin.git`

Hope this help!

```
var couchbaseLiteURL = "";
var databaseName = "test";

if(window.cblite) {
     window.cblite.getURL(function(err, url) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("error launching Couchbase Lite: " + err);
            } else {
                console.log("Couchbase Lite running at " + url);
                couchbaseLiteURL = url;
            }
     });

} else {
     console.log("error, Couchbase Lite plugin not found.");
}

//jQuery Ajax function
$.ajax(
     url: couchbaseLiteURL + databaseName,
     type: PUT,
     success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
          // You can see console output from Chrome Inspect tool chrome://inspect/#devices
          // xhr.status returns a code to you. 
          console.log("success! with status: " + xhr.status); 
     },
     error: function (xhr, statusText, errorThrown) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr));
     }
);
```